# WTForms skip validation if field data is unchanged

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a Flask web app which manage all the kiosks' information. I created a WTForms object for the kiosk's information (forms.py):

```py
class KioskForm(FlaskForm):
    kiosk_name = StringField('Kiosk Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_site = SelectField('Kiosk\'s Site', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_location = StringField(
        'Kiosk\'s Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_ip = StringField('IP Address', validators=[
        IPAddress(), DataRequired()])
    kiosk_mac = StringField('MAC Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate_kiosk_name(self, kiosk_name):
        kiosk = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
            equipment_name=self.kiosk_name.data).first()

        if kiosk is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Kiosk Name existed.')
```

Suppose I want to edit an existing kiosk's information (routes.py):

```py
@app.route('/edit_kiosk/<kiosk_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(kiosk_name):
    data = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
        equipment_name=kiosk_name).first()

    form = KioskForm(kiosk_name=data.equipment_name,
                     kiosk_location=data.equipment_location,
                     kiosk_ip=data.equipment_ip,
                     kiosk_mac=data.equipment_mac)
    ... ...
```

What I wanted to do is: if someone changed a kiosk's name to another existing ones, it'll complaint the name is already existed. Which the validation is in the forms.py.

But, one problem is that if I edited an existing kiosk, perhaps changed the ip address, but name remains the same, upon submit it still complaint the name is already existed. Something must be wrong about the name validation here.

How to make WTForms skip the name validation if the name is unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution that behaves exactly what I wanted, although ended up with a slightly more clunky codebase.

In *forms.py*, add an initialiser to store the original field data, and used to compare the new data:

```py
class KioskForm(FlaskForm):
    kiosk_name = StringField('Kiosk Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_site = SelectField('Kiosk\'s Site', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_location = StringField(
        'Kiosk\'s Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
    kiosk_ip = StringField('IP Address', validators=[
        IPAddress(), DataRequired()])
    kiosk_mac = StringField('MAC Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    # Initialiser
    def __init__(self, original_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KioskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_name = original_name

    # Changed to compare the old & new data
    def validate_kiosk_name(self, kiosk_name):
        if kiosk_name.data != self.original_name:
            kiosk = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
                equipment_name=self.kiosk_name.data).first()
            if kiosk is not None:
                raise ValidationError('Kiosk ID existed.')
```

And in the *routes.py*, feed in the original name into *original_name*:

```py
@app.route('/edit_kiosk/<kiosk_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(kiosk_name):
    data = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
        equipment_name=kiosk_name).first()

    form = KioskForm(kiosk_name=data.equipment_name,
                     kiosk_location=data.equipment_location,
                     kiosk_ip=data.equipment_ip,
                     kiosk_mac=data.equipment_mac,
                     original_name=data.equipment_name
)
    ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really run this logic locally and confirm it works but I've implementing solutions similar to this in the past. Try this out and let me know if it helps you. Cheers,
-Andrew

```
def initializeKioskForm(edit_boolean):
    # only validate if edit_boolean is false
    if edit_boolean == False:
        kiosk = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
            equipment_name=self.kiosk_name.data).first()
        if kiosk is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Kiosk Name existed.')
    
    class KioskForm(FlaskForm):
        kiosk_name = StringField('Kiosk Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
        kiosk_site = SelectField('Kiosk\'s Site', validators=[DataRequired()])
        kiosk_location = StringField(
            'Kiosk\'s Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
        kiosk_ip = StringField('IP Address', validators=[
            IPAddress(), DataRequired()])
        kiosk_mac = StringField('MAC Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    return KioskForm
```

---

```
from forms import initialize_controller_form

@app.route('/edit_kiosk/<kiosk_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(kiosk_name):
    data = db.session.query(KioskConf).filter_by(
        equipment_name=kiosk_name).first()

    KioskForm = initializeKioskForm(edit_boolean=True)
    form = KioskForm(kiosk_name=data.equipment_name,
                        kiosk_location=data.equipment_location,
                        kiosk_ip=data.equipment_ip,
                        kiosk_mac=data.equipment_mac)
```

Comment: It looks like the logic above is to give developer a 'switch' whether the forms need to perform validation or not upon form initialisation, instead of checking the original field data has been changed.